# Overlay with Form posting data but refreshing back to original page

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, overlay

I need your help with a basic architecture of a JavaScript Overlay.

I have my website where I have added a JavaScript overlap which rolls out on the click of a button. The overlay has a form on it and I have set the form to post data to same page and I am getting the data and updating Database.

My problem however is that my form submission takes my back to my page where the overlay is in minimized state. I am pretty sure I am doing this incorrectly. What I want is that on click of button submit, the data gets posted to the db but the overlay stays open. Something like www.leadformix.com with a demand generation professional handbook overlap at the bottom left of page. Notice how the form submission keeps the overlay open.

Can anyone please guide me on what would be the right way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ajax.  You can use it to perform server side actions and stay on the same html page.  jQuery has an easy to use implementation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).